# Open activity from the recent activities

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

You're on an activity and you press the home button.

Then you long press home menu button, and select the activity you were on, from the 'recent activities' screen.

What method is called when the activity shows again? `onResume`, `onRestart` or any other?

Comment: `onResume` is called. Background activity may be destroyed to reclaim memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `onResume` will be called anyways even after `pause` or `stopped`.

`onRestart` may be called if activity has been `stopped` in the `background`

The recommendation is to save your data in `onPause` and rebuild it on `onResume` with some flags, so flags can tell you if `onResume` called after `onPause`/`onStopped` or Activity is freshly created.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the Android developer website

> *"... When the user leaves your activity, the system calls onStop() to stop
>   the activity (1). If the user returns while the activity is stopped,
>   the system calls onRestart() (2), quickly followed by onStart() (3)
>   and onResume() (4). Notice that no matter what scenario causes the
>   activity to stop, the system always calls onPause() before calling
>   onStop()...*"

Here is the Activity [image]

So no Matter what `onResume()` would get eventually called.

You can download the [ActivityDemo](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityLifecycle.zip) which exhibits the Android lifecycle accurately. [This](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityLifecycle.zip) should help you.